# insert sql from submit button

Tags: php, html, sql, submit

Im trying to add an entry into my database using a submit button on a php file. The table I'm adding to is called - Fixture and contains:

```
FixtureID - int PK AUTO_INCREMENT
Competition - varchar
TeamID - int
Against - varchar
Date - date
Time - time
HomeScore - int
AwayScore - int
```

The code for the php is below.

```
<div id="container">
<div id="content">
<h2>Add New fixture</h2>
<hr />
<form action = "new_fixture.php" method="post" >    
<p>Add Fixture :</p><br />

<input type="text" name="comp" size="25" placeholder="competition" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="text" name="vs" size="25" placeholder="against" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="date" name="date" size="25" placeholder="date" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="time" name="time" size="25" placeholder="time" />
<br />
<br />
<input type ="submit" name="updateinfo" id="updateinfo" value="Add player">

</form>
</div>
<div>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Fixture VALUES  ('','$comp','9','$vs','$date','$time','','')");
if(!$sql) {
echo ("Could not delete rows" .mysql_error());
}
}
?>
```

Any ideas how to fix this it isn't adding to the database

Thanks

Comment: How does it not work? Do you get any errors? What have you done to troubleshoot this?

Comment: nothing is added to the database thats the issue. No errors just it doesnt upload to the database as required

Comment: i was wondering if it had anything to do with the time and date fields?

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

to

```
if(isset($_POST['updateinfo'])) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NULL` for your primary key instead of empty string `''`, and use numbers for your `int` columns:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Fixture VALUES(NULL,'$comp',9,'$vs','$date','$time',0,0)");
```

**EDIT** For the question in your comment about the date/time format:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Fixture VALUES(NULL,'$comp',9,'$vs',STR_TO_DATE('$date', '%m/%d/%Y')),STR_TO_DATE('$time','%h:%i'),0,0)");
```

Comment: its adding to the database now except for the date and time columns. Date is being inserted as 0000-00-00 and time as 00:00:00. I did notice in the input type fields for date and time it inputs it in this format DD-MM-YYYY and for time HH:SS . How do i solve this?

Comment: @user3535330 What is your database? The accepted date/time format is different from database to another.

Comment: using go daddy so phpmyadmin so sql

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Fixture VALUES  ('','$comp','9','$vs','$date','$time','','')");
if(!$sql) {
echo ("Could not delete rows" .mysql_error());
}
}
?>
```

You check if there is a POST param named submit sent.
You have 3 possible fixes here:

1. Check if the submit button is sent: 
   Change :

   if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

with :

```
if(isset($_POST['updateinfo'])) {
```

As your input button's name is **updateinfo**

1. Change the name of the submit button to **submit**
2. Check if !empty($_POST)

Comment: read the answare @Racil Hilan

The query has also an error, you try to insert an CHAR by FixtureID.

Set this field by insert to **NULL** RTM: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: its adding to the database now except for the date and time columns. Date is being inserted as 0000-00-00 and time as 00:00:00. I did notice in the input type fields for date and time it inputs it in this format DD-MM-YYYY and for time HH:SS . How do i solve this?

Comment: True, there is an error in your mysql query. 
Null can not be inserted into a primary key so a better solution for the above is to specify the columns of the table for the row that you are inserting.


EDIT ( sent it by mistake) 
example:
INSERT INTO logs (`site_id`, `time`,`hits`) VALUES (1,"2004-08-09", 15)
And do not send the primary key as it will auto increment every time you insert something in it.

Comment: @user3535330: DateFormat! You can't add in other format. Show supported Formats from your DB-Engine

Comment: Your query has actually multiple errors:
1. there are no variables $comp, $date, $time, $vs
but instead you have $_POST['comp'], $_POST['vs'], $_POST['date'], $_POST['time']


Date has to be this format:
YYYY-mm-dd
And time has this format:
H:i:s

You can change the query to the following:
instead of date write **date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['date']))**

Your query would look like:
INSERT INTO table ( Competition, Against, Date, Time ) VALUES ( '".$_POST['comp']."', '".$_POST['vs']."', '".date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['date'])."', '".date('H:i:s',strotime($_POST['time']))."')

Comment: @iCe: *Null can not be inserted into a primary key* This is WRONG! You can use the auto_sequence by using **0** or **NULL**
RTM:
mysql: **No value was specified for the AUTO_INCREMENT column, so MySQL assigned sequence numbers automatically. You can also explicitly assign 0 to the column to generate sequence numbers. If the column is declared NOT NULL, it is also possible to assign NULL to the column to generate sequence numbers.**

Comment: You're right, but i actually meant you shouldn't send null to a primary key index, insert method has a fieldset(meaning field list as in my example above) that can be sent and by default it increments the field. No point in telling mysql
"Look i don't have a value for this field so do what you have to do", it does it(the autoincrement) by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out - not a pro at this, but i might work.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['updateinfo'])) {
$comp = $_POST['comp'];
$vs = $_POST['vs'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$time = $_POST['time'];
$query = "INSERT INTO Fixture SET Competition='$comp', Against='$vs', Date='$date', Time='$time' ";

if ($mysqli->query($query)) {
 $message = "It worked - Post inserted.";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";

}else{
echo 'something went wrong';
}
}
```